# How to Listen to a client socket and pass that message to another Socket IO

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

[image: My Application Outlook]

I have a scenario where my client communicates with a socket-middleware system. So when a message is typed by the user, the client emits an event to the middleware app. In the middleware app we save the transcript and mashup the data and send the text back to a third party user.

**Middleware.js**

```js
const io = require('socket.io')(http)
let URL = 'https://XXXXX.com'
let clientSocket = require('socket.io-client')(URL)

io.sockets.on('connection', (socket) => {
    // This event is emitted when client sends a message to the WEB SOCKET Server.
    // User's data is the callback
    socket.on('client_message', async (data) => {
        // mashup the data 
        clientSocket.emit(data)
    })

})

clientSocket.on('agent_message',(data)=>{
    io.to(sockets[senderId]).emit('bot_message', response)
})
```

**Issue**
I am facing duplicate messages issue up on every client_message. Because for every request, 'clientSocket.emit(data)' is being called.

Comment: Where are you getting the duplicate messages?  In this code `io.to(sockets[senderId]).emit('bot_message', response)`, where does the `senderId` come from?  You don't show that.

Comment: Your code appears to be doing exactly what you asked it to do.  Every time you receive a `client_message` from any client, you are calling `clientSocket.emit(data)`.  If that's not what you want to happen, then what is it that you want to happen?

Comment: Yeh, But upon  new connection , we get a new event listener and the existing listener is also active and the messages are being duplicated(incremented per connection)

Comment: Unrelated, but I suggest not using `io.sockets.on` but rather `io.on`. They do the same thing, but for the sake of code readability `io.on` is better

Comment: Upon new connection, you're listening with `socket.on()`.  That's not a duplicate listener.  That's a socket that doesn't have that listener.  Please read the first sentence of my first comment here and kindly answer that question.  I don't know what duplicate you're getting.  Duplicate from what?  I'm trying to help here, but the question is not clear enough for my dense head to understand what your problem is.